# htaccess "Header set X-Robots-Tag noindex" works for .html only, doesn't work for .jpg or .pdf

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, pdf, noindex, x-robots-tag

I have a shared webspace where I use `.htaccess` with no problems so far.
Today I created a directory with some PDFs and JPGs inside. Not secret, but I don't like to see it in search results. Structure is like this:

`http://example.org/foo/bar/`

```
# http://example.org/foo/.htaccess

Header set  X-Robots-Tag noindex
```

This should set the header for any file in `/foo` and `/foo/bar` 
Result:

`http://example.org/foo/`, `http://example.org/foo/test1.html/`, `http://example.org/foo/bar/`, `http://example.org/foo/bar/test2.html/` return the X-Robots header as expected.

Doesn't work for `http://example.org/foo/test.jpg/` or `http://example.org/foo/bar/test.pdf/`.

`Header set  X-Robots-Tag` works only for HTML, not for JPG and PDF and likely other files.
I also tried things like `<files "*.pdf">`.

I think this should work, yes? What can I do?

jj

EDIT: Server is a combination of NGINX and Apache

Comment: Have you tried adding a second header directive - `Header always set  X-Robots-Tag noindex`? What is with the trailing `/` after the images?

Comment: Yes, `test.jpg/` with `Header alway set` works. What does this mean? BTW, server is NGINX, is that relevant?

Comment: I commented when your question was tagged `apache`, not `nginx`. I haven't used `nginx` for many years, and I don't think it supports `.htaccess` or similar.

Comment: Apache maintains two separate tables of response headers, `always` and `onsuccess`. You can read the [details here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header). I don't know how nginx handles response headers.

Comment: I think my provider has that combination of NGINX and Apache described here: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/web-servers/apache-and-nginx-web-servers-linux/apache-with-nginx.70837/ (didn't realize that until today). Probably best to open a ticket and ask them (last time this was a waste of time ...)

Comment: ... and  thanks for your comments, I'm on the right track now it seems!